# Are Klingon threats towards the Federation serious?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon

A few days ago I watched "[Aquiel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aquiel_(episode))" (episode 6x13 of Star Trek The Next Generation). I noticed a line spoken by [governor Torak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Torak_(Governor)) where he claims that he found Aquiel Uhnari's escape pod wandering around and "**she was lucky he didn't destroy her**".

I recall similar threats from the Klingon side towards the Federation in many previous episodes. How should we understand this? The Klingon Empire has a peace treaty with the Federation and therefore is its ally. It is impossible to imagine (at least to me) that one side of a peace treaty will attack another one, right? So, are these threats some kind of Klingon nature, style, culture or way of life<sup>1</sup>, and therefore can be easily "ignored"? Or are these real and serious?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For example: you tell your best friend that you're going to kill him, at least once per week, so he can feel your friendship is warm, right? Somehow, I can't imagine one member of NATO treating another one this way. Or any similar ally example.</sub>

Comment: “The Klingon Empire is a part of Federation” — nope. They’re separate and vaguely equivalent galactic powers. You’re quite right that during most of *The Next Generation* period there’s a peace treaty between them, but the Klingons didn’t join the Federation.

Comment: Fine. But (from the perspective of my question) that doesn't change anything. You can't (seriously) warn, that you kill someone, which who you had sign peace treaty, right?

Comment: well, it changes the line “The Klingon Empire is a part of Federation”. And you *can* tell someone you’ve got a peace treaty with that you’re going to kill them, it just means you’re dissolving the peace treaty.

Comment: "The Klingon Empire has a peace treaty with the Federation and therefore is its ally"  That's not how a peace treaty works.  Having a peace treaty does not mean you are someone's ally, it just means that you are at peace with each other.  For instance, the US has a peace treaty with China, but neither countries are allies.

Comment: @Robert: Except, that in this time-frame, there is an actual alliance between the Federation and the Klingon Empire.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite An aside, for where that may have come from, in TNG 2x17 Wesley does say "before the Klingons joined the Federation" even though it never happened.  I think it's just usually taken as Wesley being confused.

Comment: @Izkata: I recall reading that the Klingons were originally going to be Federation members when *TNG* started, as per Roddenberry's desire, but that the writers wisely backed away from that idea. That line of Wesley's may have been written before the decision to keep the Empire a separate polity. TangoOversway would know more than I would about the subject.

Comment: @Izkata: ooh, I didn’t know that. There’s a typo in your comment though — you’ve got “confused” where you should have “a f—ing idiot”.

Comment: @Robert Your comment drifts toward diplomacy and politics, which isn't main topic here. Even though China and USA are not allies, it isn't possible (or at least, it would be very surprising) if one of these countries would start warnings about invasion, killing people etc., right. That is the point of my question. No matter, how you name this "cooperation" between Klingon Empire and Federation, such threats are very unusual IMHO.

Comment: @trejder, yes, you're right.  Having someone make threats like that while you have an active peace treaty is odd.

Comment: @Robert: Not necessarily, though it is rare. It was hardly unusual, for example, for Nazi Germany to threaten dire consequences to their own allies if they didn't obey edicts from Berlin, with the kidnapping of Hungarian leader Admiral Horthy's son as the most egregious example. Germany was also on very friendly terms with Poland until approximately three seconds before they invaded them. Same with the USSR, actually. But Nazi Germany is obviously an extreme example. For the most part, you're right.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Since, I'm from Poland, your middle comment just made my day! :> "_Germany was also on very friendly terms with Poland until approximately three seconds before they invaded them_". LOL! Thanks! :>

Comment: @trejder: Yeah, they actually were. It comes as a surprise to a lot of people. But that's of-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the Klingon Empire is most assuredly NOT part of the Federation; if they were, how could the two go to war with each other in *DS9*? They are allied, but this does not imply that the Klingons are members of the Federation. If they were, they wouldn't have such a huge star fleet, for one thing, nor could they launch wars of aggression against Cardassia without Federation acquiescence.

Secondly, the exchange is hardly unusual in Federation-Klingon diplomacy. It was said by George Kennan, former secretary to the US Ambassador to Moscow - and later the US National Security Advisor, I believe - that the Soviet Union only understood negotiation from a position of strength. If you asked them nicely for something, they would promise to give it some thought, then do nothing. But if you simply told them what you wanted, and backed it with the threat of force, they would probably give it to you. This happened when the US threatened to intervene in Iran in 1946, the US refusal to allow a joint occupation of Japan, and the Berlin Airlift. The US did not apply pressure over Poland, so the Soviets therefore didn't budge.

The same is true of the Klingons. They are clearly a militaristic culture, and negotiating from a position of weakness would only invite their contempt. Threatening them, even non-seriously, was the best way to ensure their co-operation. In "Unification I," Captain Picard asked the Klingons for a Bird-of-Prey to infiltrate Romulan space, telling Gowron's representative "you will have our gratitude. If you don't supply the vessel, I'm sure others in the Empire will, and they will have our gratitude." This is a very blunt threat to back another side in the fluid politics of Klingon society, where Gowron had only just emerged Chancellor after a bloody civil war.

Such threats work both ways. Gowron routinely refused to consider returning Cardassian or Federation territory even after the Klingons allied with the Federation against the Dominion. Martok expressed contempt for Cardassians and humans even though he stood amongst the corpses of Cardassians whose rebellion against the Dominion had ensured the Federation Alliance's victory. Worf's brother, Kurn, threatened to kill Riker during "Sins of the Father." This is simply how Klingon society seems to treat negotiations.

Comment: “how could the two go to war with each other in DS9” — spoilers!

Comment: Perfect answer with a lot of real-world examples. Thank you. @PaulD.Waite -- assuming, I haven't seen DS9 yet, you're 200% sure! :>

Comment: Political considerations aside, it was also common for Klingon captains to use space debris for target practice. They could have easily shot the pod without bothering to scan it for life-forms first.

Comment: Did you really call spoilers on a show from 20 years ago? ;)

Comment: @BBlake: People on this site call spoilers from 50 years ago.

Comment: @BBlake: I did indeed. Spoilers are relative, and from the question’s wording it’s at least possible the OP is working through TNG-era Trek, meaning the DS9 Klingon war is a spoiler for him. Just because something’s old doesn’t mean it’s permeated the culture enough for its major story points to be known.

Comment: Statute of limitations for spoilers is clearly 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit speculative and baseless, but my impression is that both interpretations are true.

Klingons will make threats far more freely than Starfleet officers would, and many of them won’t be intended to be followed up with action.

But at the same time, the Klingons would be more likely to actually dissolve the peace treaty with the Federation (or have an individual ship captain ignore it) than the Federation would, so at least some of their threats could well be carried out if the situation doesn’t get resolved to the Klingon’s satisfaction.